# Unknown code fragment - 0xff000000

Tags: c#, java, xcode, image-processing, hough-transform

I came across this program under hough transform in java example. But im doing my project in C#, i cannot figure out what is ment by this partial code  "**0xff000000** ". what this piece of code - 0xff000000 is it a color? if its color how can i convert it C#?

```
private void drawPolarLine(int value, int r, int theta) {
            for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {

                for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {

                        int temp = (int)(x*Math.cos(((theta)*Math.PI)/180) + y*Math.sin(((theta)*Math.PI)/180));
                    if((temp - r) == 0)
                         output[y*width+x] = 0xff000000 | (value << 16 | value << 8 | value);

                }
            }
        }

if ((input[y*width+x] & 0xff)== 255) {
    //.........
}
```

Comment: No matter which programming language you're converting from or to, you should always endeavor to replace [Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) with constants that mean something.  `private static final int COMPLETELY_OPAQUE = 0xFF000000;` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hexadecimal number 0xFF000000 is expressed in dot-decimal notation as 255.0.0.0. The digits 0 and 1 represent?

A hex character does not normally represent a specific decimal character. It represents 4 bits in a Base 2 (Binary) number system. This is why dot-decimal notation is used for IP addresses. It makes it more readable for a user because a Hex FF is ALWAYS used to represent a full octet of binary ones which can always be displayed as 255 in dot-decimal notation.

Lets say you want to represent 1111 1111 0001 1111, you would use 0.0.255.31 in dot-decimal format even though FF1F in Hex is actually 65311 in a Base 10 (Decimal) number system.

```
Hex ..........Decimal.......bin
0...............0..............0
1...............1..............1
2...............2..............10
3...............3..............11
4...............4..............100
5...............5..............101
6...............6..............110
7...............7..............111
8...............8.............1000
9...............9.............1001
A..............10............1010
B..............11............1011
C..............12............1100
D..............13............1101
E..............14............1110
F..............15............1111
10............16........0001 0000
```

The programming language Java does not provide you with pointers,  so you can't access the memory location of objects/integers and other things. I'm not sure if c# does, but if you truly want to understand how memory locations work, I would learn a language like c++.

Comment: You can work with pointers in C#, but I don't think that's relevant here. The question is about numbers, not memory addresses.

Answer (score 4):

it's just the HEX representation of a number.
0xF=15, 0xF0=240, 0xFF=255, 0xF12A=61738, ...., 0xff000000=4278190080

It's easier to understand and more meaningful in coding when you're doing bitwise operations

Answer (score 3):

In RGBA notation, the leftmost byte is generally the alpha channel. It indicates the amount of transparency of a given pixel. 0x00 is for a fully transparent pixel, and 0xff for a fully opaque one (as if, no transparency at all.)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space.

Answer (score 2):

The code `0xff000000` is just a hexadecimal representation of a number. Specifically, the number 4,278,190,080. You can use it the same way in C#.

In this code, it probably represents a color, but it's hard to tell without knowing more about what you are doing.

Comment: i converted the hexadecimal value in to int Convert.toInt32(0xff000000 ). and it worked. thank you for help

Comment: Well, that shouldn't work. That value is too big for `Int32`. Your code throws an exception for me.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment what you think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: sorry i was trying to vote for this answer! accidentally down voted the answer! your answer is correct, in fact my solution didn't work.